# Find a mongo subcollection by id

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I need help with this query. how i can find a subcollection?

Collection clientes

```
db.clientes.find({
    _id: ObjectId("587cc2d8704ae610d3741e6b")
}); {
    "_id": ObjectId("587cc2d8704ae610d3741e6b"),
    "razonSocial": "CREXELL",
    "cuit": "20-12121212-0",
    "vsat": [{
        "CPA": 8682,
        "IP": "149.126.35.61"
    }, {
        "CPA": 5500,
        "IP": "149.126.36.109",
        "_id": ObjectId("587cdb2af073f02a251361e8")
    }, {
        "CPA": 1234,
        "IP": "1902312",
        "_id": ObjectId("587d05fb930d504018ef8e01")
    }],
    "__v": 7
}
```

I need get something like as:

```
{
            "CPA": 5500,
            "IP": "149.126.36.109",
            "_id": ObjectId("587cdb2af073f02a251361e8")
        }
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation to achieve this, but you also need to know the _id you are looking for within the subdocument array.

```
db.clientes.aggregate([
    // Find the document matching the _id only
    { $match: { "_id": ObjectId("587cc2d8704ae610d3741e6b") } },
    // Split all vsat array elements into separate documents
    { $unwind: "$vsat" },
    // Match only the case where the _id matches 587cdb2af073f02a251361e8
    { $match: { "vsat._id": ObjectId("587cdb2af073f02a251361e8") } },
    // Choose the elements we wish to return
    { $project: { "vsat": 1, "_id": 0 } }
])
```

Results in:

```
{ 
    "vsat" : { 
        "CPA" : 5500, 
        "IP" : "149.126.36.109", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("587cdb2af073f02a251361e8") 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! This query return empy for me

`db.clientes.aggregate([{ $match: { "_id": ObjectId("587cc2d8704ae610d3741e6b") } },{ $unwind: "$vsat" },{ $match: { "vsat._id": ObjectId("587cdb2af073f02a251361e8") } },{ $project: { "vsat": 1, "_id": 0 } } ]) ;
> `

Comment: Try adding each stage of the pipeline one at a time.  First this:

db.clientes.aggregate([
    { $match: { "_id": ObjectId("587cc2d8704ae610d3741e6b") } }
])

Then this: db.clientes.aggregate([
    { $match: { "_id": ObjectId("587cc2d8704ae610d3741e6b") } },
    { $unwind: "$vsat" }
])

etc...